# Restful API design: how should user's and authority's endpoints be?

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture, endpoint

Based on similar questions, i came to the conclusion that the most convenient way to design this endpoints to GET requests should be something like:

```
GET /v3/users/
GET /v3/users/{userId}
GET /v3/users/{userId}/authorities
GET /v3/users/authorities/{authId}
```

My question is how should be the next endpoints:

```
1. Create authorities
POST /v3/users/authorities 
POST /v3/users/{userId}/authorities 

2. Update authorities
PUT/PATCH /v3/users/authorities/{authId} 
PUT/PATCH /v3/users/{userId}/authorities/{authId} 

3. Delete authorities
DELETE /v3/users/authorities/{authId} 
DELETE /v3/users/{userId}/authorities/{authId}
```

What do you think? Intuitively, i go with first option on all cases but maybe is not the nicest thing passing the userId from body (i see it nicer passing it from url). Or should i implement both endpoints maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second approach is cleaner and more standard.

```
PUT/PATCH/POST/DELETE.. /v3/users/authorities/{authId} - [1]
PUT/PATCH/POST/DELETE.. /v3/users/{userId}/authorities/{authId} -[2]
```

Here, for example, if you pass authId in uri, why not userId ? The standard you will be following here is "resource/{uniqueId}/attribute/{uniqueId}". Ideally in your back-end code, you first look up for the specific resource, and then look up specific attribute(s) for the same resource with the keys/ids passed in the uri. Id is omitted when the action is going to affect all the resources!

If you use the approach [1], it looks like you are trying to add/update/delete an authority for ALL users! Definitely that is not the case.

It is doable to send the userId in the form/post data, but not the correct approach. In your form/post data, you should send the values that are going to be added/updated (in case of PUT/POST). Something like {authType: 'Admin', isGlobal: true, effectiveFrom: '12/12/2015'}. Obviously, userId does not fit here.

Comment: Thanks! What about GET authority? should be still /v3/users/authorities/{authId}

Comment: @jscherman No! You should follow the same standard there as well. Sorry, I didn't mention.

Comment: @Arghya_C One last question, what about if i would want to search all users that have the authority "A"?

Comment: You can use GET /v3/users?authType=A. The resource for this call is users. And A is not an identifier for the user(s), rather a search query.

Comment: but then GET /v3/users should return all the users WITH its authorities, right? (which as i have it right now, it doesn't show them)

Comment: That depends on your design and needs. If you need the authorities of the users at client side, return users with authorities. If that is not required, and you just want to filter users with the authority type given, you can do the filtering at back-end code and return plain user objects to client.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that I agree with the answer Arghya placed, but I do think there could be a case made for shortening those UPDATE and DELETE urls down to `v3/authorities/{authId}`.

Of course, this would assume that the `authId` is unique for that Authority across the application. I personally don't see a point in specifying a user. Either the person that is hitting that route has access to the resource or not.

Just remember that RESTful is just an architectural style. You should do what fits best into your technology stack and makes the most sense for you and the clients interacting with this API.